# NodeJS decryption fails while using Crypto. What is the issue?

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

```
var decipher = Crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cfb', 'testtesttesttesttesttest', 'testtesttesttest')

Error: Invalid key length
    at new Decipheriv (crypto.js:267:16)
    at Object.createDecipheriv (crypto.js:627:10)
```

This is the error I get. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Using a key of an unsupported/invalid length - as per "Invalid key length"? (Does the key have to be extended first?)

Comment: @user2864740 the iv key length?

Comment: The key itself has to be 256 bits, however that is achieved. Is that done internally?

Comment: @user2864740 Yes. The issue is with the IV

Comment: Even if I use var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16), I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

¿if we try another way ? as in this example:

```
function encryptdata(key, text) {

  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
                   hash.update(key);
  const keyBytes = hash.digest();

  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cfb', keyBytes, iv);
  let enc = [iv, cipher.update(text, 'utf8')];
  enc.push(cipher.final());
  return Buffer.concat(enc).toString('base64');
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The key needs to be exactly 32 bytes in length.
Please try the below code to see if it works.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var key = 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest';

try{
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cfb', key, 'testtesttesttest');
var encryptedData = cipher.update("hello", 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
console.log(encryptedData);

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cfb', key, 'testtesttesttest');
var decryptedData = decipher.update(encryptedData, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
console.log(decryptedData);
} catch(exception) {
    console.error(exception);
}
```